# What does "charging affair" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not a native English speaker, so I had a trouble when translating an article which is about [wearable smart watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018). I'm confusing what does "have made charging a non-micro USB charging affair" mean in the following context:

> To their credit, many of the manufacturers **have made charging a
>   non-micro USB charging affair**, though Motorola’s Moto 360 is probably
>   the most handsome execution of the idea. Sony, for reasons unknown has
>   chosen the ol' plug-it-in approach with the Smartwatch 3. None of
>   these methods would matter to me if didn’t have to go through the
>   exercise on a daily basis though.

P.S: Author is reviewing wearable smart watches in the above context.

Comment: Even to this native speaker, that is a confusing and ugly sentence.  I'm honestly not sure what the writer was trying to say.  The manufacturers _have made charging a matter which does not involve micro USB_?

Comment: I believe @stangdon is correct. The writer does not like having to plug charger (which often have a micro USB connector on the end) into a smart watch in order to change it. He probably prefers an inductive charging system. The sentence is awful.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the affair is the act of charging the device.

> af·fair
>
> 1. an event or sequence of events of a specified kind or that has previously  been referred to.

so they have made the affair of charging a "non-micro USB charging" type of affair.

Confusingly written, but there you go.